# How can i convert this Elastic query to Nest in C#?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to convert this (working) Elastic query to C# using Nest, but there is a problem with the timestamp.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2023-08-01T00:00:00",
              "lte": "2023-08-01T23:59:59"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "message",
            "query": "status"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": ["message"],
  "size": 10000,
  "from": 0
}
```

This is a working Nest query:

```
            var results = _client.Search<EmailLogResultMessage>(s => s
                .Index(file)
                .Size(pageSize)
                .From((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Must(sh => sh
                            .Match(mp => mp
                                .Field("message")
                                .Query("*status*")
                                  )
                                )
                         )
                     ).Source(so => so.Includes(i => i.Field("message")))
                                                        );
    public class EmailLogResultMessage
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
```

but i want to include this part:

```
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2023-08-01T00:00:00",
              "lte": "2023-08-01T23:59:59"
            }
```

The problem with this is that GreaterThanOrEquals only accepts double values, so I can't do this:

```
GreaterThanOrEquals("2023-08-01T00:00:00").LessThanOrEquals("2023-08-01T23:59:59").
```

Here is what i have tried according to this:
[How mapped the timestamp args in range filter using NEST for ElasticSearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73569616/how-mapped-the-timestamp-args-in-range-filter-using-nest-for-elasticsearch)
The query is valid, but the results are zero, so something there is not working.

```
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2023, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2023, 8, 1, 23, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Utc);


            var results = _client.Search<EmailLogResultMessage>(s => s
                .Index(file)
                .Size(pageSize)
                .From((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                .Query(q => q
                    .DateRange(r => r
                        .Field(f => f.Timestamp)
                        .Format("epoch_second")
                        .GreaterThanOrEquals(startDate)
                        .LessThanOrEquals(endDate)
                    )
                )
                .Source(so => so.Includes(i => i.Field("message")))
                .Sort(sort => sort
                    .Descending("@timestamp") 
                )
            );


            public class EmailLogResultMessage
            {
                public string message { get; set; }
                [Date(Format = DateFormat.epoch_second, Name = "timestamp")]
                public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

            }
```